# question with stopping times

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we define for $A\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^n})$ the first hitting time

$$ T_A:= \inf\{t\ge 0;X_t(\omega)\in A\}$$

where $X=(X_t)$ is a stochastic process, adapted to a Filtration and with right-continuous paths. Now suppose that $A$ is open then I want to show:

$$\{T_A<t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$$

for all $t\ge0$ and where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is a element of the filtration. In the book there's a hint, we should show $\{T_A<t\}=\cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q},0\le q<t}\{X_q\in A\}$.
One inclusion, i.e $\supset$,is obvious. Unfortunately I got stuck at the other. Since the paths are right continuous, my first thought was to construct a sequence of rational decreasing to $T_A$, however I do not see why such a sequence should exist and I do not see how I should use that $A$ is open. 
Some help would be appreciated!

hulik

Comment: Let $\omega$ in the LHS. You have for a $r<t$ that $X_r(\omega)\in A$. Let $\{r_n\}$ a dicreasing sequence of rational numbers which converges to $r$. Since the path are right continuous, $X_{r_n}(\omega)\to X_r(\omega)\in A$, so for $n$ large enough $X_{r_n}(\omega)\in A$. Now take $n$ such that $r_n<t$ and you are done.

Comment: @ Davide Giraudo: This was exactly what I did, but why does such a sequence exist? Of course there is a sequence of rationals converging to $r$. But why can I choose a decreasing one? Sorry, this should be a basic Analysis question but I don't see right now.And I don't see where "we" use that $A$ is open in this argument.

Comment: Fix an integer $m$. Then $r$ is in a interval of the form $[j2^{-m},(j+1)2^{-m})$ for some integer $j$.  So take $r_j=(j+12^{-m})$.

Comment: Of course I means $(j+1)2^{-m}$ in the last comment. Openness is need to ensure us that $X_{r_n}(\omega)\in A$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the following:
$$\{T_A<t\}=\cup_{0\le s<t}\{X_s\in A\}=\cup_{q\in \mathbb{Q},0\le q<t}\{X_q\in A\}.$$
The first equation  is easy, but the second equation is troubling you. You should try to understand why if $X_s\in A$ for some real value $s\in[0,t)$, then also $X_q\in A$ for some rational $q\in[0,t)$. This is where you use the fact that $A$ is open and that the sample path is right-continuous.

Comment: @hulik Do you agree that every interval of the form $[s,s+\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon>0$ contains a rational?

Comment: @ Byron Schmuland: Shame on me!I did a very bad error in reasoning!

Comment: @hulik Yes, it is crucial! The sample path $s\mapsto |s-\sqrt{2}|$ hits the set $A=\{0\}$, but *not* at any rational time.